# Firebase function not working - how to write a value when a value is inserted

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am creating a record in Firebase with javascript at

`/babies/{babyId}/users/{userId: true}` and would like to have a function insert a record at: `/users/{userid}/babies/{babyId: true}`

I have this procedure:

'use strict';

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.onBabyCreated = functions.database.ref('/babies/{babyId}/users/{uid}').onWrite(event => {
    const usersRef = event.data.ref;
    const uid = event.params.uid;
    const babyId = event.params.babyId
    const original = event.data.val();
    console.log("uid: " + uid + " and " + babyId)
    console.log("Original data " + JSON.stringify(original))
    const obj = {}
    obj[babyId] = true
    return functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}/babies/{babyId}').push().set(obj)
});
```

I get an error that : `functions.database.ref(...).push is not a function`

Why?  Here is how I add data in the javascript code:

```
var dr = firebaseGetConnection().ref('babies/' + babyId + '/d').push()
dr.set(object.toJS())
return dr
```

This creates a value - why can't I create it the same way above?  Everything else works, I have a babyId and uid set properly and it logs the correct message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
return admin.database().ref(`/users/${uid}/babies/${babyId}`).set(true);
```

The `functions` SDK is only for defining the triggers of a function. To actually write to the DB, you need the Admin SDK.